# How can I have ssh-agent warn if using a particular key?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have an older SSH key that I'm replacing, and I would like ssh-agent to warn me if it used the older key, so I know to update it on that server.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it confirm before using a key with the `-c` option to `ssh-add`. From the manpage:

```
 -c      Indicates that added identities should be subject to confirmation
         before being used for authentication.  Confirmation is performed
         by the SSH_ASKPASS program mentioned below.  Successful confirma‐
         tion is signaled by a zero exit status from the SSH_ASKPASS pro‐
         gram, rather than text entered into the requester.
```

That's per-key. So you can add one key with `-c` and the other one without. The default program will ask you to enter your passphrase; but you can just click OK or Cancel (that's what it means by signaled by the exit status).

Comment: Perfect; and using https://github.com/TimZehta/mac-ssh-confirm it works on a Mac, too.